# Tensorflow Data Augmentation - How to add new images into the dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am attempting a very simple data augmentation, to increase my dataset for a class that has very limited image. My idea of data augmentation is to simply take the classes that is lacking the data and run a function that generates 3  additional images that differ via rotation.

However, I am unsure on how to I add the concat or add the data back into the dataset and thereafter concat that dataset back into the main dataset that contains all my other classes.

My attempt

```
# Loading the dataset of the class that are lacking in images
lacking_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(DATA_DIR + '/3/*')

# Some preprocessing function that do rescaling and normalizing the pixel value
processed_lacking_ds = lacking_ds.map(preprocess_function)

# For every image of the dataset, I would like to produce additional 3 images through image rotation
for image, label in processed_lacking_ds:
    imageShape = image.shape
    imageType = image.dtype
    for i in range(3):
        image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_rotation(image, 180)
        imageTensor = tf.constant(image, dtype=imageType, shape=imageShape)
        imageDS = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(imageTensor)
        # This is where I'm stuck at, I'm would like to concat or append the newly generated imageTensor and its respective label into processed_lacking_ds.
        # Thereafter concat processed_lacking_ds into another dataset (aka processed_ds below) that contains the other classes for training
```

Some other information that could be helpful

```
# This is how my main dataset will look like
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(DATA_DIR + '/*/*')
preprocess_function = partial(preprocessing, target_size=image_size)
processed_data = list_ds.map(preprocess_function).shuffle(100)
train_data = processed_data.take(train_data_size).batch(batch_size)
test_data = processed_data.skip(train_data_size).batch(batch_size)

# This is how I will run my model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs=10
history = model.fit(
  train_data,
  validation_data=test_data,
  batch_size=batch_size,
  epochs=epochs,
  callbacks=[tensorboard_callback]
)
```

If there is a much more efficient way of doing this, please let me know.

Comment: It's always a good idea to read the documentation before posting questions here. tf.data.Dataset API has a [concatenate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#concatenate) method.

Comment: @gobrewers14 I actually have went through different kind of methods, one of them like you said using tf.data.Dataset.concatenate, but it will not work the way I prefer it to be hence I came here and ask the question. concatenate only accepts 1 argument. As mentioned in the question, I am stuck because I'm not sure how to concatenate when concatenate only accept 1 argument but my processed_lacking_ds types (tf.float32, tf.int32), one for the image and one is for the label

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [preprocessing.RandomRotation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/RandomRotation) layer to augment your training data:

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  # ...
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
  # ...
])
```

See the official example: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation#data_augmentation_2

And after the training you would remove this layer.

Comment: Hi Darius, thank you for your suggestion. Im actually looking for a method to do this outside of my model itself. I would not like to handle the preprocessing inside my layer.